# Can't initialize D struct member with Range

Tags: d

I'm attempting to learn D and ran into an issue with structs and initialization. When the following code is compiled as `rdmd -version=templat code.d`, I get a bunch of errors like:

```
> dmd -version=templat code.d
D:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\random.d(1610): Error: static variable initialized cannot be read at compile time
D:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\random.d(1653):        called from here: rndGen()
D:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\random.d(1653):        called from here: uniform(a, b, rndGen())
code.d(8):        called from here: uniform(1u, 7u)
D:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\range\package.d(3470):        called from here: (*function () => uniform(1u, 7u))()
D:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\range\package.d(3387):        called from here: gen.popFront()
code.d(8):        called from here: generate()
code.d(13): Error: template instance `code.Dice!(1u, 7u)` error instantiating
```

I assume this has something to do with needing to be able to statically resolve the `uniform(Lo, Hi)`. But I am at a loss as to how solve this issue. When I compile with `rdmd -version=variabl code.d`, I encounter no issues.

For what it's worth, my goal is to be able to define a "dice" type so that I can implement ranges, operator overloading, etc. on it to get a feel for this in D.

```
import std.range : generate ;
import std.random : uniform ;

version(templat)
{
struct Dice(uint Lo, uint Hi)
{
    auto values = generate!(() => uniform(Lo, Hi));
}

void main()
{
    Dice!(1, 7) d6;
}
}

version(variabl)
{
void main()
{
    auto d6a = generate!(() => uniform(1, 7));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for `generate!` to work it needs to cache the first result when it's constructed, but setting a default struct values happens at compile-time. (so tries to run uniform() using ctfe...)

What you could do is use alias like this:

```
import std.range : take, generate;
import std.random : uniform;
import std.stdio, writeln;

alias Dice(uint Lo, uint Hi) = generate!(() => uniform(Lo, Hi));

void main()
{
    auto d6 = Dice!(1, 7);

    writeln(d6.front);
    writeln(d6.front); // same as above because you didnt pop it
    d6.popFront();
    writeln(d6.front);
    d6.popFront();

    d6.take(3).writeln;

}
```

Also, here is an example of createing a range directly without useing `generate!`.

```
import std.range : take;
import std.random : uniform;
import std.stdio, writeln;

struct Dice(uint Lo, uint Hi)
{
    void popFront()
    {
        front = uniform(Lo, Hi);
    }

    static bool empty = false;

    uint front;
}

auto makeDice(uint Lo, uint Hi)(){
    auto dice = Dice!(Lo, Hi)();
    dice.popFront();
    return dice;
}

void main()
{
    auto d6 = makeDice!(1, 7);

    writeln(d6.front);
    writeln(d6.front); // same as above because you didnt pop it
    d6.popFront();
    writeln(d6.front);
    d6.popFront();

    d6.take(3).writeln;

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to initialize a struct member with a `generate!` range?